# Shadow casting to specific objects only

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Im using blender 3.6. In blender I want object A to only cast a shadow on object B and not cast a Shadow on object C, while object B still casts a shadow on object C using cycles render engine. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try it through the *Compositor*: in *View Layer 1* make *Collection 1* (with object B and C) visible:

[image]

In *View Layer 2* make *Collection 2* (with object A and B) visible:

[image]

Enable film transparency, render the image, open the *Compositor*, mix the 2 *View Layers* through a *Color > Alpha Over*:

[image]